# Magento2: Composer installation error

Tags: magento2, install, composer

I'm trying to install composer on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine, for **Magento2 installation** but the following error occurs:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json
```

I check that JSON is already installed through below command -

`aptitude show php5-json`

which shows below result -

```
Package: php5-json                
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
Priority: optional
Section: php
Maintainer: Debian PHP PECL Maintainers <pkg-php-pecl@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 117 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libjson-c2 (>= 0.11-3~), phpapi-20121212, ucf
Conflicts: php5-json
Breaks: php5-common (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~), php5-common (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~), php5-dev (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~), php5-dev (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: php5-dev (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~), php5-dev (< 5.5.0~rc1+dfsg-1~)
Provided by: php5-common
Description: JSON module for php5
 This package provides a module for JSON functions in PHP scripts. 

 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially
 suited for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
```

please help to overcome with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your `php -m | grep json` output? Do you have "json" as a result? If not then you need to enable this module in php.ini. A list of used php.ini files can be retrieved using `php --ini`.

Comment: `php -m | grep json` output is nothing, What I have to write in `php.ini`?

Comment: Usually it is enough to run "sudo apt-get install php5-json" and it should get installed properly. You should find in your php.ini commented line "extension=json.so", if it is not present, then add it.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the PHP extension not only **installed** but actually **loaded** by the PHP interpreter. You can see it by running the [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php) function.